# html border center of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an HTML page which has a table center aligned. 
Now I want to have a border to the entire page but on the center.

```css
table {
  min-width: 900px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 900px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: white;
  border-style: double;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <img src="logo.png" class="logo" /> </td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <hr>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type="number" class="input"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="input"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="input"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="input"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Student ID Number</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Middle Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am looking for something like this. http://ibb.co/gyqTY6 
My content is displayed in the entire page and I like to have a border to the center of the entire page.

The above styling gives me border on the entire page but I want to have a border on the center of the entire page.

Comment: Please attach HTML code as well.

Comment: a border in the center ??

Comment: Yes, border in the center.

Comment: share you html sample

Comment: Added HTML code

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout. They should only be used to render tabular data.

Comment: What does *"I want to have a border to the entire page but on the center."* mean?

Comment: I am looking for something like this. http://ibb.co/gyqTY6
My content is displayed in the center of the page and I like to have a border in the center of the entire page.

Comment: @jackysatpal There is no border in the center of the page in that image you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```css
     .container{
       border: 1px solid;
    margin: 3%;
    padding: 3%;
    margin-right: 18%;
    margin-left: 18%;

    }
table{
margin:0 auto;
}
table th{
min-width:20%;
}
    body{
      background:red;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <h2>Basic Table</h2>
      <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
      <table class="table" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am looking for something like this. 
http://ibb.co/gyqTY6

Comment: @jackysatpal How is that border in your screenshot centered? It is not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you want, but perhaps applying a border only to the table is what you meant.

In that case, style the table accordingly.
Edit: especially, avoid applying `border` to the body, this won't get you the desired result.

Minimal suggestion:

```css
table {
  min-width: 900px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 900px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <img src="logo.png" class="logo" /> </td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <hr>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> <input type="number" class="input"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="input"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="input"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="input"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Student ID Number</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Middle Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables should not be used for layout. They cause the rendering of the page to be slowed down and are not semantically correct. They should only be used to render tabular data.

Also, don't use `h1`, `h2`, etc. because of the way they make the text look, use them because they are the logical start of a new section of a particular importance. Any text can be styled to look like any other text.

So, the above two points really are talking about "semantics". The HTML tags you use should describe the data they convey, not the look of the data on the page. This allows for the data to be consumed anywhere, by any device and that device should understand what the data is. CSS is meant to make that data look how you'd like it to look. Don't confuse the two.

Now, you can "style" content to be displayed as a table using the CSS `display` property, which allows you to avoid using the `<table>` element and the related elements as well. But, your layout looks like simple columns, so you could approach this in a number of ways, but here's one:

```css
html, body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body {
  background: white;
  border: double;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size:1.3em;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px double black;
  margin:25% 5px;  /* Adding the same margin to top and bottom creates vertical alignment */
  padding:10px;    
}

.column {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- By placing everything in a wrapper element, you can move it and style it easily -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <hr>
  </div> 
  <div class="column">
    <input type="number" class="input"><br>
    <span>Student ID Number</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <input type="text" class="input"><br>
   <span>Last Name</span>      
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <input type="text" class="input"><br>
   <span>First Name</span>      
  </div>
  <div class="column">    
   <input type="text" class="input"><br>
   <span>Middle Name</span>      
  </div>
</div>
```